# Grep in many directories, but only look in each dir's specific subdirectory, not all sub dirs

Tags: grep, recursive

My case:

```
dir1 
  subdir1
      FooFile
  subdir2

dir2 
  subdir1
      FooFile
  subdir2
```

So, if I `cd dir1`, I can easily do something like `find . | xargs grep "Foo"` in order to list the names of all files containing `Foo`.

The problem is that there are so many subdirectories and files, that this search takes a very long time. I'd like to recursively go into each main dir, and then go specifically only to the ONE subdir (subdir1) and then do the grep.

What is the best way for me to list the names of all files containing `Foo` from all directories? For every differently named directory, `subdir1` is always one level below `dir1`, and is always named `subdir1` exactly.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to “list all file names containing `Foo`” (in which case the base case would be `find . | grep Foo`, no `xargs`), or are you trying to list all files containing `Foo` (which corresponds to your sample code)?

Comment: Alas, the OP "joined" Stack Exchange, asked this question, and departed, all in the space of one minute — and did not register.  We may never get the clarification we seek.

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
grep "foo" */subdir1/*  */subdir1/.*
```

? (based on your current question, this seems to fit the bill. unless there are so many "subdir1" subdirs that the shell can't supply the whole list to grep.

You can add -q and test if it exit with 0  if you just want to see if a "foo" appears in the file

You can also do a recursive grep, and then discard what you don't need (heavy on i/o, but simple) :

```
grep -r "foo" . | grep "^\./[^/][^/]*/subdir1/[^/][^/]*:"
```

(See comments below : here, even if name contains ":", this will work as you did find a filename underneath subdir1, and that file does contain foo. It could miss a file which contains a newline in its name, though, as in the 2nd grep it won't see the first "./firstleveldir/" name, so the 2nd grep will dismiss it...)

Comment: (1) I don’t think the OP just wants to look *in* all (sub)directories named `subdir1`; I think she wants to look *in **and under*** (recursively) all (sub)directories named `subdir1`.  But I agree that the question is a little unclear.  (2) The question says that a search of the entire directory tree is prohibitively slow, so your second answer is probably unacceptable.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Grepping the output of `grep` to look for the filenames that the first `grep` found is unreliable.  It can fail if (3a) a filename contains newline, or (3b) a *file* contains text that looks like a filename.  (You could possibly fix the second one by using `[^/:]` instead of `[^/]`.)  (4) At the end of your command, you say `[^/*]` where I believe that you mean `[^/]*`.

Comment: @G-man: thanks, i indeed typoed, and I will edit that. I also agree that adding `:` inside the regexps would help against some false positive (files with newlines, and other edge cases, really... but you never know). My solution should work when there is nothing too special (no newline in a dirname or filename, etc)

Comment: It occurred to me after I wrote my first comments that testing for **`:`** can cause incorrect results if a directory name contains a colon — which, of course, *is* legal in Unix.  Sometimes you just can't win.

Comment: @G-man indeed ^^ ... I ll edit again. shows that it's not a good way on my part, then...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look *in **and under*** all (sub)directories named `subdir1`
that are one level down from the top level, you can do

```
find */subdir1 …
```

If you’re looking for files whose *names* contain `Foo`, you can do

```
find */subdir1 -type f -name "*Foo*" -print
```

Or you could do

```
find */subdir1 -type f -print | grep "Foo"
```

but that would include every file *under a directory*
whose name includes the string `Foo`,
for example, `dir42/subdir1/Foods_I_Like/pizza`
and `dir42/subdir1/Foods_I_Like/chicken`.

If you’re looking for *files that contain* `Foo`
(i.e., whose ***contents*** contain `Foo`), you can do

```
find */subdir1 -type f -print | xargs grep "Foo"
```

Notes:

- This works because `find`’s synopsis (usage) looks like

  ```
  find [options] [starting-point...] [expression]
  ```

  i.e., you can invoke `find` once on multiple starting points; as in:

  ```
  find   dir1/subdir1 dir2/subdir1   [expression]
  ```
- This handles files and directories whose names include space(s) just fine.
- If you’re looking for files ***or directories*** whose names contain `Foo`,
  leave out the `-type f` from the corresponding commands.
- Of course you must quote `"*Foo*"` and you must not quote `*/subdir1`. 
  Quoting `"Foo"` is optional —
  it doesn’t hurt, but you don’t need to quote
  words that don’t contain any special characters.
- You can leave out the `-print`, since it’s the default action.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a script, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type d | while IFS= read -r pathname
do
    for name in "$pathname"/subdir1/*Foo*
    do
        [ -f "$name" ] && echo "$name"
    done
done
```

with the usual caveats about newlines in pathnames.  Tested with this tree:

```
./dir2
./dir2/subdir1
./dir2/subdir1/FooFile
./dir2/subdir2
./subdir1
./subdir1/FooFile
./dir spacew
./dir spacew/subdir1
./dir spacew/subdir1/FooFile
./dir spacew/subdir2
./dir1
./dir1/subdir1
./dir1/subdir1/FooFile
```

the script produced

```
./subdir1/FooFile
./dir2/subdir1/FooFile
./dir spacew/subdir1/FooFile
./dir1/subdir1/FooFile
```

The question was ambiguous regarding the use of `grep` (as written, there was no difference versus `echo`, except for the possibility of using regular expressions rather than shell wildcards).  Alternatively, you could use `grep` directly:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*Foo*' | grep -E 'subdir1/Foo[^/]*$' | while IFS= read -r pathname
do
    echo "$pathname"
done
```

Further reading:

- [read - read a line from standard input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) (POSIX)

Comment: Shouldn't that first line have a `-maxdepth 1` operator?

Comment: OP should clarify, but there's no reason subdir1 couldn't have a directory under it also named subdir1

Comment: (1) I don’t think the OP wants to look in *all* (sub)directories in the directory tree named `subdir1`; I think she wants to look in all (sub)directories named `subdir1` that are one level down from the top level.  But I agree that the question is a little unclear.  (2) I don’t think the OP just wants to look *in* all (sub)directories named `subdir1`; I think she wants to look *in **and under*** all (sub)directories named `subdir1`.  But I agree that the question is a little unclear.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Since the question says “file names containing `Foo`” and `grep "Foo"`, I believe that the OP wants to find files with names like `FavoriteFoods`, and so your `Foo*` glob and your `/Foo[^/]*$` regexp are too restrictive.  (4) Why do you say `| while IFS= read -r pathname; do echo "$pathname"; done`?  Why not just do `find . -type f | grep -E 'subdir1/Foo[^/]*$'` or even `find . -type f -regex '.*/subdir1/Foo[^/]*$'`?  P.S. Your `grep -E 'subdir1/Foo[^/]*$'` matches `dir1/xyzzysubdir1/FooFile`, which is an unwanted result.

Comment: That's several questions.  Short: I made the choice to avoid matching filename "subdir1", and did not make the change to use `read -r` (though in this case it was harmless).  And I did not suggest `-regex` (not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), not derived from the question).